# Where can I find alternatives to...?

Tags: software-recommendation

There has been a couple questions here regarding alternatives to certain programs, and I'm sure as more people start using Ubuntu, and join this site, there will be more people looking for alternatives to programs they used in their previous operating system.

Therefore I figured I start a thread to list different sites that list alternatives to programs.

(Please just post one link per answer).

Answer (score 11):

**[LinuxAlt](http://www.linuxalt.com/) - The Linux Alternative Project**

From the website:

> My goal is to provide an informational website available to all linux users. The website is currently in beta form and I will periodically update the database with Windows software and the Linux equivalents and alternatives.

The site has a very lengthy list of Windows programs and their Linux alternatives. The website is apparently still under active development.

Comment: This one looks a bit abandoned, honestly.  The last updates seem to be from 2011, and it includes alternatives for AIM (AOL Instant Messenger).  Maybe worth downvoting unless and until it shows activity.  Defunct software (which a lot of the links on that page are) can be dangerous.

Answer (score 8):

**[osalt](http://www.osalt.com) - open source *as* alternative**

From website:

> Our mission is to provide easy access to high quality open source alternatives to well-known commercial products. And remember that open source software is also a freeware alternative.

Just like the other sites suggested it gives alternatives to proprietary programs.

Comment: The front page on that website was last updated in 2012 with a message about the launch of IPv6.  As far as I can tell, none of the software recommendations have been updated since around that time either.  On the bright side, many of their top open-source picks are still updated today.  However, it's missing some key recent additions like MariaDB.  Also still includes AOL Instant Messenger (defunct for 5 years now) and alternatives.

Answer (score 8):

[**alternativeTo**](http://alternativeto.net/)

From website:

> AlternativeTo is a new approach to finding good software. Tell us what application you want to replace and we give you great alternatives, based on user recommendations

This site has a sizable list of alternatives for a sizable number of programs.

Comment: The only site in this list currently that appears to still be actively updated as of 2022, and yet it has the fewest upvotes currently.  I have no opinion here; just checking the "freshness" of the links in these answers since there was a new answer today (since deleted).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Keyword search every package available from the apt-get repositories as well as any ppa installed on your system.